# Remove list item without using store in Sencha Touch/ExtJS

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a `list` whose items changes dynamically. With a button, I add items this way:

```
myList.insert(index, {
    //Component
});
```

and it works properly. Now, I want to remove the `index`th item. I have tried this:

```
myList.remove(index);
```

but it does nothing. How can I do that? I insist, I can't do it using a store.

Comment: You can't, the list is a store backed component. Attempting to do otherwise will just end up causing problems.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will have to reimplement it using stores...

Comment: No store needed if you have a list with different types of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove a record in a list using this:

```
myList.removeAt(index);
```

[Sencha docs for this](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/modern/Ext.dataview.List.html#method-removeAt)